# NAnt:Path system environment variable

Tags: windows, nant

Why do we need to create nant.bat file in a directory that is included in the PATH system environment variable. What actually is this Path system environment variable? What if i dont do it?

Answer (score 2):

This `PATH` variable is used by the OS to look for folder paths when we execute a command.

If you don't do that, you will have to call `nant.exe` in full path which is quite annoying.